# How to allow all characters (Chinese, Spanish, Korean, etc) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

So I have a column in my table called 'names' which is a VARCHAR (60), but I am trying to accept international characters properly.  For Chinese/Korean characters it is just putting '?' in place of the actual chracters.  What is the collate that works properly with the international 2 byte standard(s)?  I also need to be able to SELECT data from this column based on case sensitivity so `TEST` will pull a different row than `Test`.  Thanks

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sett your database collation to `utf8-general-ci` and the database will handle characters correctly.